# BNO055 mounted orientation configuration

Tags: orientation

[image: BNO055 9-DOF absolute orientation sensor]

For this BNO055, [I am trying to figure out the correct `transpose` and `sign` tuples](https://github.com/JasonKleban/Autopilot/blob/main/sensorLoop.py) (or the byte values) for reorienting the sensor so that it will tell me the heading "forward" (from the perspective of this photographer), pitch forward/backward (+- don’t care which), and roll left/right (+- don’t care which).  That is, the board is mounted on the parked vehicle such that the plane of the breakout board is perpendicular to the ground.

I have read the [chip's datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST_BNO055_DS000_12.pdf) (near page 25, though it doesn't look to me like it should be any of those examples) and tried to study the orientation handedness to choose correct values of transpose and sign, but for whatever reason I cannot figure it out.  Here I think I'm trading -Z for X, X for Z.  After calibration, the heading is wrong and pitch and roll sensitivity are swapped.

```
imu = BNO055(i2c, transpose=(2, 1, 0), sign=(1, 0, 0))
# imu.set_offsets(bytearray(ubinascii.unhexlify('e1ff0400ebff4bfe1d0232ff0000feff0000e803a702')))
```

1. What are the correct transpose and sign tuples for this mounting orientation?
2. Are the sensor offsets/calibration that I extract and reuse relative to the raw, untransposed sensors or are those adjustments applied after the transposition?  I’d guess *raw*, but any time I change the transpose & sign values, the existing calibration seems bad because the chip stays in calibration mode for much longer than when I reuse offsets from the same orientation settings.

### Update

The bno055 quickstart guide has extra info on the heading interpretation which I find helpful:

https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/application_notes_1/bst-bno055-an007.pdf

[image]

Comment: Should "from the perspective of this photographer" actually say "from the perspective of this *photograph*", i.e. without the "er"? That is to say, when you state "That is, the board is mounted on the parked vehicle such that the plane of the breakout board is perpendicular to the ground" that means that the writing "9-axis Abs. Orientation" is on the bottom, closest to the ground (with the rest of the board pointing up)?

Comment: I do mean "photographer" because I'm trying to indicate that "forward" is looking through the board.  I'm trying to establish a direction with two points: the photographer and the board, with the board oriented as shown when the viewer is looking through it to the forward direction.

Comment: Darn adafruit linking (and google boosting) an old version of the datasheet.  Here's the latest:  https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bno055-ds000.pdf  Others with basically the same problems as me: https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=108290&p=541754#p541754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my best reading, this doesn't match the documentation, but this seems to give me good heading, roll, pitch values for my mount orientation.

```py
imu = BNO055(i2c, transpose=(1, 2, 0), sign=(1, 1, 0))
```

and I also believe that the calibration must be done specifically for each transpose/sign reconfiguration.  I hope this helps someone.